# Suspicious get in my website to the URL htttp://p3nlhclust404.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net/SharedContent/HostingRedirect.html

Tags: get, wampserver

My website has suspicious GET to the site

```
http://p3nlhclust404.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net/SharedContent/HostingRedirect.html
```

[image: link to error in my hosted website]

The problem is that I get this error in all local projects in wampserver, and also in my hosted website (ovh hosting).

Why is my site making requests to this suspicious domain? Is this a security incident?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you solved your problem by now, but just in case someone else is stuck on this weirdness in the future, I had the same "issue":

I'm using `<name>.webdev.com`for my WAMP virtual hosts and I mistyped it `wevdev` somewhere. `wevdev.com` and all its subdomains redirect to that http://p3nlhclust404.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net 404 page.

Maybe you made the same typo!